# Number of solutions of equation $\tan^{-1}(2\sin x)=\cot^{-1}(\cos x)\;$ in $[0,10\pi]$.

Tags: trigonometry, inverse-function

Number of solutions of equation $\tan^{-1}(2\sin x)=\cot^{-1}(\cos x)\;$ in $[0,10\pi]$.

**My Approach:**

Using the formula $\tan^{-1}(x)\;+\;\cot^{-1}(x)=\dfrac{\pi}{2}$ our equation get converted to

$\tan^{-1}(2\sin x)+\tan^{-1}(\cos x)\;=\dfrac{\pi}{2}$

S0 $2\sin x \cos x=1$

$\implies  \sin (2x)=1$

$\implies 2x=(4n+1)\dfrac{\pi}{2}\; \implies \; x=n\pi\;+\;\dfrac{\pi}{4}$

But answer given is $x=2n\pi\;+\;\dfrac{\pi}{4}$.

Where Am i going wrong?

Comment: The $\tan^{-1}(x) + \cot^{-1}(x) = \frac{\pi}{2}$ identity only works if the arguments are the same, but yours aren't.

Comment: @Dan Actually I Used $\; \;$ $\tan^{-1}(\cos x)\;+\; \cot^{-1}(\cos x)=\dfrac{\pi}{2}\; \implies\; \cot^{-1}(\cos x)=\dfrac{\pi}{2}-\tan^{-1}(\cos x) $

Comment: For example, $x=\frac 54\pi$ is a solution. So, I think that the answer given is wrong.